# Cannot use template function type in constant context with MSVC 1930+ (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, function-templates, constant-expression, template-instantiation

When I have a function template like this:

```
template<class T>
T func(T bar) {
    return bar;
}
```

I cannot use its instantiation in constant context with the latest MSVC compiler:

```
constexpr bool b = std::is_function_v<decltype(func<int>)>; // fails with error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
```

```
static_assert(std::is_compound_v<decltype(func<int>)>); // fails with C2057: expected constant expression
```

You can test it yourself in [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/czM7n74Kv).

It works with older MSVC versions and with GCC and Clang. Is it a compiler bug, or is it expected behavior?

Comment: Works for me: `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.30.30709 for x64`

Comment: Weird... after I updated to `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.31.31104 for x64`, the code does not compile with the `/std:c++20`. I get `error C2057: expected constant expression` error. It has to be a regression. Someone should file it to Microsoft :)

Just for the record, `/std:c++17` works

Comment: I've created an issue on the VS website: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-use-template-function-type-in-con/1677526